# listView setOnItemClickListener android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to open an Activity called Bihar.class when I will click on Bihar in listview. and also open other activities as well when clicking on other items in the list. so  How to  implement this please help me.

I have made custom list and custom adapter for this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvFUJ.png)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<State> stateNames = new ArrayList<>();
        stateNames.add(new State("Andhra Pradesh","Amaravati"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Arunachal Pradesh","Itanagar"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Assam","Dispur"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Bihar","Patna"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Chhattisgarh","Raipur"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Goa","Panaji"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Gujarat","Gandhinagar"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Haryana","Chandigarh"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Himachal Pradesh","Shimla"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Jharkhand","Ranchi"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Karnataka","Bangalore"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Kerala","Thiruvananthapuram"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Madhya Pradesh","Bhopal"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Maharashtra","Mumbai"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Manipur","Imphal"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Meghalaya","Shillong"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Mizoram","Aizawl"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Nagaland","Kohima"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Odisha","Bhubaneshwar"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Punjab","Chandigarh"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Rajasthan","Jaipur"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Sikkim","Gangtok"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Tamil Nadu","Chennai"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Telangana","Hyderabad"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Tripura","Agartala"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Uttarakhand","Dehradun"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Uttar Pradesh","Lucknow"));
        stateNames.add(new State("West Bengal","Kolkata"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Andaman and Nicobar Islands","Port Blair"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Chandigarh","Chandigarh"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman & Diu", "Daman"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Delhi","Delhi"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Jammu and Kashmir","Srinagar(Summer" +
                ") Jammu(Winter)"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Lakshadweep","Kavaratti"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Ladakh","Leh"));
        stateNames.add(new State("Puducherry","Puducherry"));

       StateCapitalAdapter adapter = new StateCapitalAdapter(this,stateNames);
       ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);

       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


           }
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your State class to have another member `Class activityClass;` which is a reference to the Activity class name for that State and add those States like following:

```
stateNames.add(new State("Assam", "Dispur", Assam.class));
stateNames.add(new State("Bihar", "Patna", Bihar.class));
...
```

Now, change your listener like following

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, stateNames.get(position).activityClass);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

This will launch your preferred Activity for that State.